# Users can't sign in after changing from cookie session to server-side session storage (Devise, Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, devise

I have also changed the domain of the cookie so that it would work on subdomains ("Switched from `domain.com` cookie to `.domain.com` cookie

The issue is users can't log in. Unless they clear their cookie or log in on incognito mode.

After a user logs in, they are just taken back to the sign in page without any errors.

Logs are showing no errors other than a 302, here's an example:

```
  Started POST "/users/sign-in" for 174.235.55.66 at 2015-05-16 18:38:20 +0000 
May 16 11:38:21 abc app/web.1:  Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as HTML 
May 16 11:38:21 abc app/web.1:    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"email"=>"email@domain.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}} 
May 16 11:38:21 abc heroku/router:  at=info method=POST path="/users/sign-in" host=www.bidvine.com request_id=f3f8fd11-acc5-443a-866d-46c554bcabb1 fwd="70.53.68.47,173.245.55.66" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=454ms status=302 bytes=794 
May 16 11:38:21 abc app/web.1:  Redirected to http://www.bidvine.com/admin 
May 16 11:38:21 abc app/web.1:  Completed 302 Found in 392ms (ActiveRecord: 35.2ms) 
May 16 11:38:21 abc app/web.2:  Processing by Admin::RequestsController#index as HTML 
May 16 11:38:21 abc app/web.3:  Started GET "/users/sign-in" for 173.245.55.66 at 2015-05-16 18:38:21 +0000
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the application secret? This would void any existing cookies.

Comment: i just did but it didn't do anything. Right now the cookie only holds an id, that maps to a sessions table in the db. I doubt secrets really apply here

Comment: In secrets.yml you have secret_key_base. Change that value and all cookies will reset. DO NOT FORGET to restart the server after you change this file.

Comment: `secrets.yml` was [introduced in Rails 4.1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#config-secrets-yml). Older rails apps use `config/initalizers/secret_token.rb`